# Paid app accidentally deleted and now can't re-download: says I "already own" the app

Tags: google-play-store, installation, apk

I paid for and downloaded an app from the Play Store. Afterwards, I accidentally deleted this app with Titanium Backup instead of a different app that I intended to delete instead.

Now, when I go to Play Store, it shows the deleted app as installable, and I try to install it again. It prompts me for payment info, which I enter, even though I paid for it once before (I don't mind paying twice, if I have to). But then, Google rejects my installation attempt and says that I "already own" the app.

I'm stuck, because now I can't re-download or re-install the app. How can I tell Google that I want them to either (1) accept my second payment and let me install the app again, or (2) make the APK available to me again because I already paid for it?

To be clear, I am quite willing to make a second payment. This is not about the money. I just want to re-install the app that I accidentally deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I figured it out ...

1. Go to https://play.google.com/apps
2. Log in with the same credentials that are used on my device
3. A list of all my installed apps is shown. Find the deleted app and click on its icon
4. An "Installed" button shows up. Click on that button
5. A window pops up with an "Install" and "Cancel" button. Click on the "Install" button.

This caused my device to start downloading and installing the app. Now it has been successfully re-installed.

Problem solved!

PS: It would be nice if Google allowed us to perform this same function from the Play Store app on our devices, so we don't have to go to a browser and access https://play.google.com/apps.

Comment: Under normal circumstances you should be able to reinstall the app as any other. My guess is titanium "deleting" it didn't uninstall it correct

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened. Anyway, I'm glad that this option is available for cases such as this one.